# Erro HTML Loader no electron-webpack

Tags: javascript, react, webpack, electron

Estou buscando uma solução para rodar; electron e react seguindo uma estrutura MVC. Achei o módulo electron-webpack que aparentemente extende sobre webpack padrão.

Seguindo a documentação configurei o `electron-webpack.json` e executei o comando `electron-webpack dev`. O comportamento esperado era que a janela do electron abrisse, porém o seguinte erro foi emitido no console:

> ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
>       Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>       ValidationError: Invalid options object. HTML Loader has been initialized usin  g an options object that does not match the API
>   schema.
>        - options has an unknown property 'url'. These properties are valid:
>          object { preprocessor?, attributes?, minimize?, esModule? }

Pensei que fosse algum erro da minha parte ao configurar. Então baixei o ["quick-start"](https://github.com/alexdevero/electron-react-webpack-boilerplate#readme) do projeto, instalei as dependências: `npm i` e tentei executar novamente: `electron-webpack dev`. Ocorreu o mesmo erro.

Segue as configurações dos arquivos:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "electron-webpack dev",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.4.1",
    "electron-webpack": "^2.7.4",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0"
  }
}
```

electron-webpack.json

```
{
    "title": "Caixa",
    "main": {
        "sourceDirectory": "src/main"
    },
    "renderer": {
        "sourceDirectory": "src/view"
    }
}
```

Output completo:

```
> project@1.0.0 dev /home/leydev/Desktop/project
> electron-webpack dev

┏ Main -----------------------

  Hash: d16cbab28f9b85dd56f5
  Version: webpack 4.42.0
  Time: 278ms
  Built at: 03/20/2020 9:23:03 PM
    Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  main.js  33.5 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
  Entrypoint main = main.js
  [0] multi ./node_modules/electron-webpack/out/electron-main-hmr/main-hmr ./src/main/index.js 40 bytes {main} [built]
  [./node_modules/electron-webpack/out/electron-main-hmr/main-hmr.js] 582 bytes {main} [built]
  [./src/main/index.js] 42 bytes {main} [built]
  [electron-webpack/out/electron-main-hmr/HmrClient] external "electron-webpack/out/electron-main-hmr/HmrClient" 42 bytes {main} [built]
  [source-map-support/source-map-support.js] external "source-map-support/source-map-support.js" 42 bytes {main} [built]

┗ ----------------------------
┏ Renderer -------------------

  ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:9080/

┗ ----------------------------
┏ Renderer -------------------

  ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
  ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/leydev/Desktop/project/static, /home/leydev/Desktop/project/dist/renderer-dll

┗ ----------------------------
┏ Renderer -------------------

  ✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: a83e02f87f1da754da63
  Version: webpack 4.42.0
  Time: 1164ms
  Built at: 03/20/2020 9:23:06 PM
   2 assets
  Entrypoint renderer = renderer.js
  [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js css-hot-loader/hotModuleReplacement ./src/view/index.js 64 bytes {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/css-hot-loader/hotModuleReplacement.js] 3.05 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/css-hot-loader/node_modules/normalize-url/index.js] 3.85 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/lodash/debounce.js] 5.96 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] 161 bytes {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:9080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9080 4.29 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.91 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/log.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 1.59 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js 402 bytes {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {renderer} [built]
  [./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.59 KiB {renderer} [built]
  [./src/view/index.js] 0 bytes {renderer} [built]
      + 35 hidden modules

  ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    ValidationError: Invalid options object. HTML Loader has been initialized usin  g an options object that does not match the API schema.
     - options has an unknown property 'url'. These properties are valid:
       object { preprocessor?, attributes?, minimize?, esModule? }

    - validate.js:85 validate
      [project]/[schema-utils]/dist/validate.js:85:11


    - ValidationError: Invalid options object. HTML Loader has been initialized us    ing an options object that does not match the API schema.

    - - options has an unknown property 'url'. These properties are valid:

    - object { preprocessor?, attributes?, minimize?, esModule? }

    - compiler.js:79 childCompiler.runAsChild
      [project]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:79:16

    - Compiler.js:343 compile
      [project]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:343:11

    - Compiler.js:681 hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err
      [project]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:681:15


    - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
      [project]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

    - Compiler.js:678 compilation.seal.err
      [project]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:678:31


    - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
      [project]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

    - Compilation.js:1423 hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err
      [project]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1423:35


    - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
      [project]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

    - Compilation.js:1414 hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err
      [project]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1414:32


    - Hook.js:154 AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook
      [project]/[tapable]/lib/Hook.js:154:20

    - Compilation.js:1409 hooks.additionalAssets.callAsync.err
      [project]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:1409:36



  Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
       1 asset
      Entrypoint undefined = index.html
      [./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js?minimize=false&url=false!./dist/.renderer-index-template.html] 555 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

      ERROR in ./dist/.renderer-index-template.html (./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js?minimize=false&url=false!./dist/.renderer-index-template.html)
      Module build failed (from ./node_modules/html-loader/dist/cjs.js):
      ValidationError: Invalid options object. HTML Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
       - options has an unknown property 'url'. These properties are valid:
         object { preprocessor?, attributes?, minimize?, esModule? }
          at validate (/home/leydev/Desktop/project/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:85:11)
          at Object.htmlLoader (/home/leydev/Desktop/project/node_modules/html-loader/dist/index.js:22:28)

┗ ----------------------------
┏ Renderer -------------------

  ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

┗ ----------------------------
```

Estrutura do projeto:

```
--myProject
  |----src
       \----main / index.js
       \----view / index.js   
  |----electron-webpack.json
  |----package.json
```

Não encontrei issue relacionadas no repositório do projeto, ou fora dele.